# How do you edit a File

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to edit a file in sharepoint for the first time.

Let me tell you the steps I have taken and how things go wrong and maybe I can get some advice.  The sharepoint file is on a server that I log into remotely.  I run the "Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration".  On the page that comes up, I click on "Manage web applications"  under "Application Management".

From there, I see the page I want to edit.  But when I click on the name of the item (which appears in red text) the area is hilighted but nothing happens.  In the ribbon menu at the top of the page there is a drop down entitled "Site Actions" but there is no option there to "edit".  Please advice.

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/SSO/SSo1_zps60b19ba2.png

I was given a username and password to "log in" because I was told I need that.  The idea was that maybe I need a special admin account to see the missing menu options to edit a page.  But, first of all, this was not the kind of username to log on to the OS.  Then I tried to use it to log onto the Sharepoint Central Administration.  But this did not work.

Please advise.

Comment: Xarzu, what exactly do you mean by "Edit a file"? A word document? An ASPX page? Typically, for office documents you will want to type in the URL of the site (ex: www.domain.com/home.aspx) and then navigate to a document library. Most common types of editing can be done from the "drop down" or "fly out" menus within the document library. I don't know if this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if you don't know how to edit a file in SharePoint or how to edit a page, you should have no reason whatsoever to be in Central Administration. Central Admin has no documents, files or pages that are edited via the browser interface. It is a tool to manage the SharePoint farm. From Central Admin, web applications are created. Web applications contain site collections. Site collections contain sites. Sites contain lists and libraries. Site pages and files in libraries can be edited.

Give the userID and password back and get reading and learning about some SharePoint fundamentals.

Comment: Yes learn the basics first as suggested by teylyn

But as per your post, I guess that 

1. You were given some credentials.
2. You logged in to the site.
3. You did not have option to EDIT.

I believe you do not have permissions to edit the page. Nothing more can be recommended.

Comment: There IS nothing to edit in CA. @Anand, what file or page exactly would ***you*** want to edit in CA?

Comment: your tone is a little mean and hurful.  Apart from that, thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Wait.  You really didn't help at all, now, did you?  What tool do you use to edit individual files.  On the other hand you started with "Please corect me if I'm wrong".  So, maybe you do not really know for sure if you can use Central Admin to edit individual files.  Ok, so I am correcting you now.  You did not provide any answers as to what tool one can use to edit an individual page (we are not talking about an html page, by the way, that I can just find on the server).  You also did not suggest any way to gain basic understanding on SharePoint.

Comment: I think Teylyn is wrong.  I think you can edit individual files in Central Admin.  I saw a menu someone online posted and it included "edit file".  The same menu I have does not include this because I was not given a username with enough permissions.

Comment: I won't get into a flame war with you. Html files are rarely touched when working with SharePoint. Content pages are edited with the browser. Pages are configured and customized with the browser, SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio. You are probably talking about editing a page. Some system pages in SharePoint will never offer the Edit option. CA consists entirely of such system pages. Please, get out of Central Admin and don't start using it for managing business content. There is nothing on any CA page that needs to be changed. Content belongs on a site.

Comment: Even CA can be edited for adding up your custom modules. CA is just another site created by default during SP installation. You can perform almost same operations as you do for normal site. Just click on SITE ACTIONS in landing page of CA & you will see.

Comment: @Anand, the OP doesn't even seem to understand the difference between a file an a page. Please don't show them ways to mess up their SharePoint farm by mucking up CA with uninformed trial and error edits of pages that they should not even have access to without proper training.

Comment: Its not about whether they should or shouldn't. The question was whether there is a way and if so how & why am I not getting the option. I believe this post needs to be closed for further comments.